# How do I use extensions in firefox selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, firefox, firefox-addon

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time;
import random;
br = webdriver.Firefox()
action = ActionChains(br)
br.install_addon("cqm.xpi",temporary=True)
```

cqm.xpi is Cookie Quick Manager and to use you need to get to link (`moz-extension://63573efb-a426-4545-8e6a-8c30d3943d5a/cookies.html?parent_url=`) but it always different and I have a question how to get this id.